# Automate execution of Snowflake worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am quite new to Snowflake and still a SQL novice.
I have a Snowflake worksheet with 30+ queries. These queries need to be run from top to bottom as the sequence is important (eg. query #3 relies on the results of #1 and #2, and so on)

I am wondering what the options are for automating the execution of these queries in the current ordered sequence.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Can you please send a sample query,  depending upon what you are doing in your queries you could move them into a stored procedure.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuKandpal, thanks for your reply. I would like to avoid sharing a sample query if possible due to the confidentiality of the data, but essentially all of my queries are select statements with or without the use of CTEs, as well as two delete statements.

Comment: Hi - what do you actually mean by “automating the execution”? Do you mean running them on a schedule or something else?

Comment: Hi @NickW, apologies, yes I mean running them on a schedule

Comment: Hi , you can create a procedure and Create a Snowflake Task.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal can you elaborate a bit more on creating a procedure and task?

Comment: The documentation on tasks is pretty clear. If you have a specific question then feel free to ask it

Comment: You don't even have to create store procedure. follow the below documentaton. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task#multiple-sql-statements-using-snowsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments have mentioned, you could create a stored procedure, and schedule this with a task.

```sql
create or replace procedure my_proc()
  returns varchar
  language SQL
  as
  $$
  BEGIN

    <your_sql_code_here>

    return 'done';
  END;
  $$
```

For more info on Stored Procedures with Snowflake Scripting, take a look here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting

And then create a task to schedule this to happen on a regular basis:

```
create task my_task
  warehouse = my_warehouse
  schedule = '60 MINUTE'
as
call my_proc()
```

More info on tasks here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task#examples

Comment: Thank you Branden-I really appreciate your help and these resources that you shared